# Layer not being correctly exported in Sketch

Tags: layers, transparency, sketch-app

I have a layer of 82% opacity on top of a background. When I choose to export *only* that layer, Sketch exports it with the background beneath it.

If I try to hide the background, then it exports the bar with the color of the artboard. That means that the colour is not right, because 82% opacity with white background beneath it gives a different colour to when the background is beneath it.

The most annoying thing is that when I export another layer (for example, the column "profile"), it exports all right without a background. The opacity is the same and all settings are the same, but the behavior is different.

I am exporting to PNG.

Does anyone know how to export this correctly?

[image]

Comment: Could you upload the sketch file so we can take a look at it?

Comment: I think you should check your layer order. For more accurate answer, Would you please upload the file.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to recreate the scenario you are describing.

[image: semi-transparent navbar background]

By selecting only the layer that is targeted for export (in my case it is only the semi-tranparent navy blue rectangle), click the `Make Exportable` button in the lower right corner.

That should result in a semi-transparent png. After doing this, I imported the resulting png to make sure is exported correctly.

[image: the rectangle below is the exported png]